# Using ionic-scroll to move and scroll canvas element

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, ionic-framework

I have a large image on a canvas element, and I'm hoping to use ionic-scroll to drag it around. I implemented the example:

```
  <ion-scroll zooming="true" direction="xy" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
    <div style="width: 5000px; height: 5000px; background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ad/Europe_geological_map-en.jpg') repeat">
    </div>
  </ion-scroll>
```

... and that works fine. Now, when I add a canvas element to the inside of the div the scroll stops working.

```
  <ion-scroll zooming="true" direction="xy" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
    <div style="width: 5000px; height: 5000px;">
      <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
  </ion-scroll>
```

The canvas shows up appropriately, and it is cut off by the ion-scroll element at 500px as expected, but the click + drag functionality doesn't work as it did with the large background. I can just scroll around with a standard mouse wheel or touch pad scroll.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I have this problem since last version of Ionic (1.2).

Before, I could zoom in / out with pinch & scroll inside the canvas, now it's no longer possible.

If it's urgent, try going back to a previous version.

[EDIT:] Ok after opened an issue on github, just use **overflow-scroll="false"** on your element.

As mentionned here:

http://blog.ionic.io/announcing-ionic-1-2/

They use native way of scrolling now. To go back to Javascript way, you have to use overflow-scroll="false", now it works.

But it seems to be an exceptional case because as Ionic says, overflow-scroll="false" is buggy. So, as an advice, just use it if you need canvas.

Comment: I'm also having this issue since 1.2, did you fill in a issue in Github?

Comment: Thanks, if you have a url let me know. I would reply in so there's more motivation to fix the issue in the next build.

Comment: Yes of course, I reopened issue for you:

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/4867

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it will work but try this.

```
<canvas id="canvas" style="width: 5000px; height: 5000px;"></canvas>
```

ion-scroll automatically restructures HTML like image below.

And creating another div tag inside it does not meet the criteria

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/affQN.png)